# Is it possible to limit the length of a string column in my seed.rb file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

UPDATE: i meant in my creates_coves.rb file in db/migrate, not seeds.rb

In my seed.rb file I have:

```
class CreateCoves < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :coves do |t|
      t.string :title, :limit=>9,:null =>false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :coves
  end
end
```

After I run `rake db:migrate`, I'm still able to create new objects with titles longer than 9 characters, and empty characters too.  Why isn't the limit or null working?

Comment: Which database backend? I bet SQLite3 doesn't bother enforcing length limits or non-NULL, it doesn't feel like an SQLite3 thing to do. :) (It'll let you stuff any object of any type into any column.)

Comment: I see, that might be it. I'm using sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use validations...

[Rails 3 Validations](http://omgbloglol.com/post/392895742/improved-validations-in-rails-3)

```
# model.rb
validates :field, :presence => true, :length => {:minimum => 1, :maximum => 9}
```

On another note, WHY are you using seeds.rb for this? This is a **migration**

Comment: My mistake I meant the create_coves.rb file, not seeds.rb. So the database will accept a string longer than 9 unless validates line is in model.rb?

Comment: or if you bypass validations... Like a direct database insert (ActiveRecord::Base.execute "...") You can try for yourself. Note that this is APPLICATION validation, not DATABASE validation...

Comment: A direct database insert should *not* bypass length restrictions on columns.

Comment: @Closure Cowboy - it will unless you also define restrictions in your migration. SQLite doesn't have this kind of validation. It doesn't support PK-FK relationships either. A direct insert doesn't go through the model at all, so it would bypass the validation 100%. Not sure where you are deriving your comment from.

Comment: That's true. He's almost certainly using SQLite on a dev box.